How to handle text/event-stream response in WSO2 Micro Integrator?
I am using WSO2 Micro Integrator to call an external API that responds with text/event-stream. I need to know if the WSO2 Micro Integrator supports processing text/event-stream responses.

Does WSO2 Micro Integrator have built-in support for handling continuous streaming responses like text/event-stream?
If it does, which mediator(s) should I use to handle this type of response effectively?
If not, are there any workarounds or custom solutions to handle SSE in WSO2 Micro Integrator?

Any guidance or examples would be appreciated.

This can be achieved by using a websocket endpoint
https://mi.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/examples/endpoint-examples/using-websocket-endpoints/
